# How can I use CUDA with vaex (a Python library）

Tags: python, cupy, vaex

my code as follow:

```
df['O_ID'] = (df.apply(get_match_id, arguments=[df['pickup_longitude'], df['pickup_latitude']])).jit_cuda()
```

When first I used this function——**jit_cuda()**,there was an error "No Module named cupy"

But, when I have installed the cupy-cuda101(Adapt to my CUDA version)
I get a new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py", line 3580, in table_part
    values[name] = df.evaluate(name)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py", line 2616, in evaluate
    return self._evaluate_implementation(expression, i1=i1, i2=i2, out=out, selection=selection, filtered=filtered, internal=internal, parallel=parallel, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py", line 5352, in _evaluate_implementation
    dtypes[expression] = df.data_type(expression, internal=False)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py", line 1998, in data_type
    data = self.evaluate(expression, 0, 1, filtered=True, internal=True, parallel=False)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py", line 2616, in evaluate
    return self._evaluate_implementation(expression, i1=i1, i2=i2, out=out, selection=selection, filtered=filtered, internal=internal, parallel=parallel, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\dataframe.py", line 5427, in _evaluate_implementation
    value = scope.evaluate(expression)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\scopes.py", line 97, in evaluate
    result = self[expression]
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\scopes.py", line 139, in __getitem__
    self.values[variable] = self.evaluate(expression)  # , out=self.buffers[variable])
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\scopes.py", line 103, in evaluate
    result = eval(expression, expression_namespace, self)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\expression.py", line 1073, in __call__
    return self.f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\vaex\expression.py", line 1120, in wrapper
    return cupy.asnumpy(func(*args))
  File "cupy\core\fusion.pyx", line 905, in cupy.core.fusion.Fusion.__call__
  File "cupy\core\fusion.pyx", line 754, in cupy.core.fusion._FusionHistory.get_fusion
  File "<string>", line 6, in f
NameError: name 'lambda_function_1' is not defined
```

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that just-in-time compilation in vaex works only for virtual columns, or expressions/columns computed mainly with various arithmetic operations using numpy methods or pure python arithmetics.

When using `apply`, a function can be quite abstract, basically whatever you want, so it may not be possible for it to be compiled.

If you can rewrite your `.apply` function using numpy expressions, then you are likely able to use the `jit_cuda` method to accelerate it. Vaex does not recommend using `.apply` anyway, since it is hard to parallelize and should be used a "last resort" of sorts.

Source: https://vaex.io/docs/tutorial.html#Just-In-Time-compilation